# c# Mod compile error (tModLoader)

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

So I am making my own Terraria Mod but I have one problem which is that when I use one the the items from my mod in a crating recipe for something else in my mod it gives me an error. I'm pretty sure the code is all fine.

This is the item that uses something from my mod:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Terraria;
using Terraria.Graphics.Effects;
using Terraria.Graphics.Shaders;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ModLoader;

namespace TestMod.Items.Weapons     //Where it is located
{
    public class BladeOfTheElements : ModItem
    {
        public override void SetDefaults()
        {
            item.name = "Blade Of The Elements";      //Sword name
            item.damage = 26;       //Sword damage - Damage is x2.5 - 43 here = 109 in game
            item.crit = -46;     //Crit chance of the weapon
            item.melee = true;      //Is it a melee item?
            item.width = 74;        //Sword width
            item.height = 74;      //Sword height
            item.toolTip = "A blade containing the power of; Fire, Ice and Forest";      //Item Description
            item.useTime = 23;       //How fast is the item? How fast does it swing or shoot?
            item.useAnimation = 23;
            item.useStyle = 1;          //How is the item used? 1 is sword
            item.knockBack = 4;     //The knockback of the item
            item.value = 100000;     //How much does it sell for? 100 = 1 Silver
            item.rare = 5;
            item.useSound = 1;      //What sound type? 1 is sword
            item.autoReuse = true;      //If it's a sword can it autoswing?
            item.useTurn = true;
            item.shoot = mod.ProjectileType("BladeOfTheElementsProj");
            item.shootSpeed = 6f;       //Speed of the projectile
        }
        public override void AddRecipes()       //How do you craft the item?
        {
            ModRecipe recipe = new ModRecipe(mod);
            recipe.AddIngredient(ItemID.BladeOfTheForest, 1);      //What do you need to craft the item? (Use 1 dirt block for testing)
            recipe.AddIngredient(ItemID.BladeOfIce, 1);
            recipe.AddIngredient(ItemID.BladeOfTheDemons, 1);
            recipe.AddTile(TileID.Anvils);        //Where is it made? Work bench, anvil, water? etc (Use worck bench for testing)
            recipe.SetResult(this);
            recipe.AddRecipe();
        }
    }
}
```

All the blades in the crafting recipe at the bottom are from my mod but I get this error when I try and compile my mod:

An error occured while compiling a mod.

```
c:/Users/Nicolas/Documents/My Games/Terraria/ModLoader/Mod Sources/TestMod/Items/Weapons/BladeOfTheElements.cs(37,41) : error CS0117: 'Terraria.ID.ItemID' does not contain a definition for 'BladeOfTheForest'
```

I'd just like to point out that when I used dirt blocks for the recipe (To test the weapon) I could compile the mod just fine.

Comment: Well https://github.com/bluemagic123/tModLoader/wiki/Vanilla-Item-IDs doesn't list `BladeOfTheForest`... what makes you think it should be there? (And no, if you're referring to a member that doesn't exist, that code *isn't* fine...)

Comment: I stated that BladeOfTheForest is an item from my mod. I want to to use it in a crafting recipe/

Comment: Instead of `ItemID.BladeOfTheForest` you need to specify the ID of that item then. `ItemID` is clearly (judging by the compiler error) a type defining the known (for the base game) item id's. Your custom item is not defined there, so you need to specify *whatever* that holds the ID of your new "BladeOfTheForest" item.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use ItemId.*Ingredient* for mod items https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/tutorial-3-items.44842/ there's a 'fix' in the comments of this if you need help

Comment: Hey Ketan! Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for posting an answer to this question! One suggestion I'd make is to transcribe any relevant information from your link into your answer, so that even if the link gets taken down, your answer is still relevant! In this case, it's less of a big deal (because if the terraria forums are taken down, modding is essentially destroyed anyways) but it's good practice to do anyways. Thanks for you post!

Answer (score 0):

```cs
recipe.AddIngredient(null, "yourweaponnamehere", 1);
```

You need to put this in place of the custom items, but not the vanilla ones. It should look like so:

```cs
ModRecipe recipe = new ModRecipe(mod);
recipe.AddIngredient(null, "BladeOfTheForest", 1);
recipe.AddIngredient(null, "BladeOfIce", 1);
recipe.AddIngredient(null, "BladeOfTheDemons", 1);
recipe.AddTile(TileID.Anvils);   
// Where is it made? Work bench, anvil, water? etc. (Use worck bench for testing.)    
recipe.SetResult(this);           
recipe.AddRecipe();
```